# Hibernate @ManyToOne mapping - automatic loading without @Id property set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

How can I force Hibernate to load my main object with some other object from *ManyToOne* relation? That's the moment where some other value is set, other than `@Id` property.

Can you check my repo with maven project on github, [HbnAddressDaoTest](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/blob/master/src/test/java/me/business/dao/hbn/HbnAddressDaoTest.java) is a JUnit test class where I'm trying this behaviour

`Address` is the entity class I would like to persist to database but only have country code from `Country`. All rows in `Country` table are constants, so `Country` object shouldn't be inserted again, only `countryId` need to be written. Is there any automation mechanism in Hibernate for this or do I have to manually load `Country` in some service transactional method before `Address` persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not posible, java can't know when `new Country("BE")` are equal to `countryDao.getByCode("BE")`, because, there are not equals, one is managed by Hibernate and the other is managed by you.

You don't give the `new Country("BE")` to Hibernate, so it can not be the same, also, went you invoke the `new Countru("BE")`, the `code` is null, and the code of `countryDao.getByCode("BE")` is not null (it was created by your SQL script and now is managed by Hibernate).

You have two options:

- Change your test to:

  ```
  Country country = countryDao.getByCode("BE");
  Address address = new Address();
  address.setCountry(country);
  addressDao.create(address);
  assertEquals(country.getCountryId(), addressDao.get(address.getAddressId()).getCountry().getCountryId());
  ```

  To test if the address is correctly persisted, or:
- Create a `CountryProvider` like this:

  ```
  public class CountryProvider {

       @Autowired HbnCountryDao dao;
       Map<String, Country> map = new HashMap<String, Country>();

       public Country getByCode(String code) {
           if (map.contains(code)) return map.get(code);
           Country toRet = dao.getByCode(code);
           map.put(code, toRet);
           return toRet;
       }
  }
  ```

  Make all of your `Country` constructors private or protected, and only access the `Country` by the `CountryProvider`.

Comment: how will hibernate join the country to address when executing get() method if it can't see constructor?

Comment: By reflection, the constructor is needed, but the visibility can be private.

Comment: I have an idea to map values with Dozer from JAXB to my domain class. In JAXB model I only have that country code. I have to put it somewhere before persisting. Because of that creating `new Country("BE")` was in my test. After mapping all values in my country object are `null` except `code`

Comment: I don't have experience with Dozer, but the mayory of the jaxb to java framework allow you to make a custom mapper, in your mapper you can calle the `CountryProducer`.