# Hibernate - how to test sequence mapping and strategy in jUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

What's the methodology of testing `@SequenceGenerator` from Hibernate? I want to be sure that every sequence is perfectly mapped, no mistake in spelling, and incrementing is done by 1. Is there any way to do this dynamically for all sequences?

Here's the sample of my sequence mapping:

```
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false, precision = 20)
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "AddressSeq", sequenceName = "ADDRESS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AddressSeq")
private Long addressId;
```

Comment: You want to create a In memory database? Hibernate creates the sequences? or is a external database? you can use reflection to get all sequences names, and query the database, but I don't think it is a unit test.

Comment: Inmemory but Oracle compatibility mode with schema preloaded from script. You can take a look on project at https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness and review it with few words. Thank you

Comment: I think you don't need to test if the sequence is incremented by 1, you need some level of trust in hibernate, but for the sequence name, you can use reflection to get all mapped classes, get they id's and get the name of the sequence, to compare it with your raw sql file, if the `CREATE SEQUENCE` exists, then it must be rigth.

Comment: Do you have any example of that kind of reflection?

Comment: I add a pull request to your project.

Comment: Can you check this question I posted. Same repo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535991/hibernate-manytoone-mapping-automatic-loading-without-id-property-set

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571146/1126380) answer to obtain a list of your entity classes:

```
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false),
                            new ResourcesScanner())
                    .setUrls(
                            ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList
                                    .toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
                    .filterInputsBy(
                            new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder
                                    .prefix("me.business.model"))));
```

And get your DDL with:

```
    ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("db/schema.sql");
    schemaContent = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(cpr
            .getInputStream())).toLowerCase();
```

And get the sequence for each class witH;

```
private String getSequenceName(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(SequenceGenerator.class)) {
            SequenceGenerator sg = f.getAnnotation(SequenceGenerator.class);
            return sg.sequenceName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The test is simple:

```
    Set<Class<?>> entities = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for (Class<?> clazz : entities) {
        String name = getSequenceName(clazz);
        if (name == null)
            continue;
        if (!schemaContent.contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
            fail("The clazz " + clazz.getSimpleName()
                    + " has a sequence called: " + name
                    + " and it doesn't exits");
        }
    }
```

You can see it [here](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/pull/1/files)

If you want to see if it works, change the sequence name in one of your entitites and run the test.

Comment: Not working. Reflection can't find classes from given package. List is empty in test method. Probably some security issues

Comment: How do you execute this? I test in my computer with ecilpse before the pull request.

Comment: I ran it in Netbeans, will try it in Eclipse also. Probably it's because of the JVM version.

Comment: Execute it with `mvn package` or `mvn test` and it will scan everthing, if you execute `mvn -Dtest=me.business.dao.hbn.CheckSequenceNames test` the classes are not loaded, It's not a IDE problem, see the executed classpath, it is not complete.

Comment: Now I have it running but always with some [exception](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/blob/master/src/test/resources/errors/exceptionWhenRunningCheckSequenceNames.txt) thrown at startup. That's some kind of warning because test was completed without that. Can you get the point where's the problem?

Comment: Please copy the exception to pastebin and share here. Or email me, you can see my email in the commits.

Comment: you can check it at the link hidden under the exception word up in my comment. it's on git repo under the /error folder in test resources.

Comment: I don't know why and what means this exceptions. see [this](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/issues/detail?id=148)